# CSS fails to apply dark-stripe and light-stripe to the table drawn by Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying a MVC sample that pulls the data from DB, and shows inside a table (using Knockout JS). I want to apply dark-stripe and light-stripe to rows. Stripes shows up only when I apply the CSS, right after calling ko.applyBindings(viewModel), not any where else.

Please help me understand what is going on here. Seems like a fundamental stuff, related to rendering of HTML.

**Pseudo code**

```
Ajax_call()
{
   Fetch data from MVC controller(Web API)
   Call knockout to construct table
   Apply stripes. Stripes appear and stay.
}

NavigateToNextPage()
{
    Call strip() from here, stripes appear JUST momentarily.
    It is so fast that I can see it ONLY when I put a break-point inside
    controller. It seems when Knockout draws the NEXT page, it removes
    stripes.

    Ajax_call();

    Same problem if I call from here. 
}
```

**Full code**

```
abc.js
=======
function getData()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "get",
        url: "/api/CollaborationSpaces/Page/" + CurrentPage,
        cache: false,
        context: this,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            //**IMPORTANT** If I call stripe() from here, I see stripes. 
        }
    });
}

var CurrentPage = 1
function stripe()
{
    $("tr:even").addClass("even");
    $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
}


function Move(pages)
{
   CurrentPage = CurrentPage + pages;
   //**IMPORTANT** 
   //If I call strip() from here, stripes appear momentarily.
   //It is so fast, I can see it ONLY when I put break-point inside
   //controller. It seems when Knockout draws the NEXT page, it removes
   //stripes
   getData(); 
   //IMPORTANT this stripe has no effect.  
   stripe(); 
}


CSS
===
.odd {
    background-color: #ebeced;
}

.even {
    background-color: #99acb9;
}

Razor
=====
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<p><span id="ItemsFound" data-bind="text: NumberOfResults"></span> Records Found</p>
<p>Page <span id="PageNumber" data-bind="text: CurrentPage"></span></p>
<br />

<table data-bind="template: {name: 'CollaborationSpaceTemplate', foreach:PersonInfoResults}" class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 class="Pager">
                <span id="back" onclick="Move(-1)">&lt; Back</span>
                <span id="next" onclick="Move(1)">Next &gt;</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<div id="LoadingDiv">Loading. . .</div>
<script id="CollaborationSpaceTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: What does the rendered markup look like? I'm guessing you're trying to apply the classNames before the HTML is rendered to the page.

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming. You are trying to add the stripes before the data is returned from the server.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Calling stripe() inside NavigateToNextPage() function will not have desired effect because AJAX call is ASYNC. It is possible that AJAX returns after the control has 
left NavigateToNextPage(), AJAX returns later and wipes out all the stripes set by NavigateToNextPage(). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (data) {
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    //**IMPORTANT** If I call stripe() from here, I see stripes. 
}
```

Yes, you should call `stripe()` from your callback (after `applyBindings`) so that the elements you are trying to add classes to are present in the markup.